# Нужно ли пересобирать maven проект при изменении файла application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties

Пишу на Java Spring и постоянно натыкаюсь на проблему того, что не понимаю в каком случае проект необходимо перекомпилировать, а в каком не нужно.

Подскажите пожалуйста подробно, проект собирается по 5 минут устал пересобирать при каждой мелкой правке.

Comment: По идее пересобирать надо даже если вы просто пробел или перенос строки где-то добавите. Это не изменит поведение программы, но иначе у вас будет собран отличающийся код. Если вы что-то в логике поменяли - то без пересборки изменения не появятся в приложении.

Comment: трудно сказать нужно ли пересобирать проект, не зная этих самых случаев, в каких-то нужно, в каких-то нет

Comment: Смотря как вы запускаете ваш проект. Если из идее или как jar, тогда не стоит. А если при помощи мавена, тогда стоит.